# Why is Task manager memory stats in GB's and resource manager is in MB's?

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory, task-manager

I want to know why in task manager memory displays in GB like 
this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

and resource manager displays memory in MB like this:

[image]

Comment: Windows has a lot of UI inconsistencies, but I think this has to do with Windows 10 reworked Task manager being newer than Performance monitor.

Comment: @LittleHelper OP is using W8 not W10.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because, when you are talking about the whole system of memory use on the system, it is just more applicable to be using GB.  Individual programs are small, therefore it uses MB, and since it has a percentage beside the GB and your overall memory for your system is large enough to be using GB, it only makes sense that it would be in GB so that the percentage makes sense and is more readable.

Comment: It's the same reason the government might report its budget in billions but I don't report my household budget that way.

Comment: I agree, great analogy!